# how to remove unwanted record from a result set in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, group-by, filtering, common-table-expression, sql-delete

hi i am modifying a Stored procedure and there are Union all statements which is selecting the data based on where condition i have added new condition as a change but the the twist here is with my new change if we get multiple records with old and my new code i have to prefer record with old code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_Select_Details_test]  
 @code VARCHAR(5),  
 @number INT,  
 @reference INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
  
 SELECT * FROM     
(    
SELECT   Code,  
    Number,  
    Reference,  
    Date,  
    Amount,  
    'F' as Type
FROM   CommonDiaries CD  
WHERE   Comment1 = 'F'  
AND    Action = ''  
AND    Code = @code  
AND    Number = @number  
AND    Reference = @reference    
      
UNION ALL  

SELECT   Code,  
    Number,  
    Reference,  
    Date,  
    Amount,  
    'T' as Type
FROM   CommonDiaries  CD
INNER JOIN  CommonDiaries CD1 ON CD.Code = CD1.Code AND CD.Number = CD1.Number AND CD.Reference = CD1.Reference 
WHERE   CD.Doc = 'T'  
AND    CD.Action = ''  
AND    Code = @code  
AND    Number = @number  
AND    Reference = @reference      

UNION ALL  

--code which i have added

SELECT   Code,  
    Number,  
    Reference,  
    Date,  
    Amount,  
    'A' as Type
FROM   CommonDiaries  CD
INNER JOIN  CommonDiaries CD1 ON CD.Code = CD1.Code AND CD.Number = CD1.Number AND CD.Reference = CD1.Reference 
WHERE   CD.Doc = 'A'  
AND    CD.Action = ''  
AND    Code = @code  
AND    Number = @number  
AND    Reference = @reference 
) As X

END
```

To achieve what i want i had added table variable to the sp and instead of Select * from i have written following code

```
DECLARE @debtdetails Table
(
    Code varchar(50),
    Number int,
    Reference int,
    Date Datetime,
    Amount varchar(max),
    Type varchar(50)
)


Insert into @debtdetails   
SELECT   Code,  
    Number,  
    Reference,  
    Date,  
    Amount,  
    'F' as Type
FROM   CommonDiaries CD  
WHERE   Comment1 = 'F'  
AND    Action = ''  
AND    Code = @code  
AND    Number = @number  
AND    Reference = @reference    
      
UNION ALL  

SELECT   Code,  
    Number,  
    Reference,  
    Date,  
    Amount,  
    'T' as Type
FROM   CommonDiaries  CD
INNER JOIN  CommonDiaries CD1 ON CD.Code = CD1.Code AND CD.Number = CD1.Number AND CD.Reference = CD1.Reference 
WHERE   CD.Doc = 'T'  
AND    CD.Action = ''  
AND    Code = @code  
AND    Number = @number  
AND    Reference = @reference      

UNION ALL  

--code which i have added

SELECT   Code,  
    Number,  
    Reference,  
    Date,  
    Amount,  
    'A' as Type
FROM   CommonDiaries  CD
INNER JOIN  CommonDiaries CD1 ON CD.Code = CD1.Code AND CD.Number = CD1.Number AND CD.Reference = CD1.Reference 
WHERE   CD.Doc = 'A'  
AND    CD.Action = ''  
AND    Code = @code  
AND    Number = @number  
AND    Reference = @reference 
) As X

END
```

Here now when i get record with type 'A' and 'T' with same Code, Number and Reference i want to pick
record over Type 'A' so it is with type 'T'

Here is a result set which i want to filter and want to show only record with Type 'T' if type 'A' is present with same Code,Number and Reference value other wise
want to show record with type value 'A'

| Code | Number | Reference | Date | Amount | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 23 | 1 | 1899-12-30 | 100.00 | T |
| 201 | 23 | 1 | 1899-12-30 | 75.23 | T |
| 201 | 23 | 1 | 2023-03-31 | 100.00 | A |

Can somebody tell me how i can achieve that. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your sample dataset, `Date` value is different between records, so do you want this excluded when considering of records are the same? This is why it is very important to have clear before and after sample recordsets and be very clear about what is and isn't functioning.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to explain if you had sample data included but the general gist is that you assign a "priority" to each row and pick the highest priority.

I strongly recommend you use aliases on your columns and also that you never use SELECT *.

Given this piece of your existing code:

```
SELECT * FROM     
(    
.... stuff
) As X
```

You can change as follows:

```
SELECT
P.Code,  
P.Number,  
P.Reference,  
P.Date,  
P.Amount,  
P.Type,
P.RecordPriority
FROM
(
    SELECT   
    X.Code,  
    X.Number,  
    X.Reference,  
    X.Date,  
    X.Amount,  
    X.Type,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY 
        X.Code,      
        X.Number,  
        X.Reference,  
--        X.Date,  
        X.Amount
        ORDER BY
        X.Type DESC
        ) RecordPriority
    FROM     
    (  
select 201 as Code, 23 as [Number], 1 as Reference, '1899-12-30' as [Date], 100.00 as Amount,   'T' as Type
union all
select 201,23,1,'1899-12-30',75.23,'T' union all
select 201,23,1,'2023-03-31',100.00,'A'
    ) As X
) As P
WHERE P.RecordPriority=1
```

Comment: i want the preference of type 'T' only when i have same values in both records except the type is different

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample dataset to explain what should be kept and what shouldn't

Comment: You added a "before" resultset but not an "after" resultset. If you want to save on back and forth questions and incorrect answers, I suggest you also add  the "required" dataset

Comment: I fixed a bug in my original code and also altered it to reflect what was provided in your sample data. As far as I can tell it does what you want but your description is so far ambiguous